# Dagger injection - when do the provide methods get called

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm experimenting a bit with Dagger on Android which seems to be a nice tool to isolate dependencies. In the first place I copied the android-activity-graphs example from GitHub: https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs

I then added a couple of classes to the ActivityModule

```java
@Module(
    injects = {
            HomeActivity.class,
            HomeFragment.class
    },
    addsTo = AndroidModule.class,
    library = true
)

public class ActivityModule {
    private static final String TAG = "Activity_Module";
    private final DemoBaseActivity activity;

    public ActivityModule(DemoBaseActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /**
    * Allow the activity context to be injected but require that it be         annotated with
    * {@link ForActivity @ForActivity} to explicitly differentiate it from application context.
    */
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ForActivity
    Context provideActivityContext() {
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ActivityTitleController provideTitleController() {
        return new ActivityTitleController(activity);
    }

    //My addition from here
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Player providePlayer() {
        Log.i(TAG, "in providePlayer()");
        return new MyAndroidTestPlayer(activity);
    }

    @Provides
    RandomNumberGenerator provideRandomNumberGenerator() {
        Log.i(TAG, "in provideRandomNumberGenerator()");
        return new RealRandomNumberGenerator();
    }
}
```

The rest of the graph initialization is identical to the example from github.

The thing that puzzles me is the fact that the injected object are null after the construction of the class they are injected into (HomeFragment)... for a while.
Again HomeFragment is more or less identical to HomeFragment from the examples in github, with a few additions of my own.
If I call whatever on either of the injected Player or  RandomNumberGenerator objects in the onCreateView() of the HomeFragment I get an error saying they are null.
However if I call them inside the inner OnClickListener - onClick() they work as expected.

Can anyone point me to the piece of knowledge I am missing to understand what is going on here?

```java
public class HomeFragment extends DemoBaseFragment {
public static final String TAG = "HOME_FRAGMENT";

public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    return new HomeFragment();
}

@Inject
ActivityTitleController titleController;
@Inject
Player player;
@Inject
RandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    if (randomNumberGenerator != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "randomNumberGenerator is NOT null");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "randomNumberGenerator is NULL!");
    }
    if (player != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "player is NOT null");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "player is NULL!");
    }
    //int randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator.getIntegerInRange(48, 50);
    //player.playTestNote();
    tv.setGravity(CENTER);
    tv.setText("Play test note");
    tv.setTextSize(40);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.playTestNote();
            int randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator.getIntegerInRange(48, 50);
            Log.i(TAG, "Text view clicked, random number is: " + randomNumber);
        }
    });
    return tv;
}
```

The classes I'm using to test with are pretty trivial (RandomNumberGenerator more so than the Player class). I'll skip the RandomNumberGenerator. Here is the MyAndroidTestPlayer which implements Player (just one playTestNote() method).

```java
public class MyAndroidTestPlayer implements Player {

SoundPool soundPool;
private static final int MAX_STREAMS = 10;
private static final int DEFAULT_SRC_QUALITY = 0;
private static final int HARDCODED_SOUND_RESOURCE_C3 = R.raw.midi_48_c3;
private static final int DEFAULT_PRIORITY = 1;
private static final String TAG = "MyAndroidTestPlayer";
private Context context;
private boolean isLoaded = false;
private int streamId;
private int soundId;

public MyAndroidTestPlayer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        createNewSoundPool();
    } else {
        createOldSoundPool();
    }
}

protected void createOldSoundPool() {
    soundPool = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, DEFAULT_SRC_QUALITY);
    Log.i(TAG, "created old sound pool");
    loadSoundPool();
}

protected void createNewSoundPool() {
    AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION).build();
    soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().setAudioAttributes(attributes).build();

    Log.i(TAG, "created new sound pool");
    loadSoundPool();
}

private void loadSoundPool() {
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                   int status) {
            isLoaded = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "Loaded");
            Log.i(TAG, "Status: " + status);
        }
    });
    soundId = soundPool.load(context, HARDCODED_SOUND_RESOURCE_C3, DEFAULT_PRIORITY);
}

@Override
public void playTestNote() {
    Log.i(TAG, "before loaded check");
    if (isLoaded) {
        streamId = soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        Log.i(TAG, "Played Sound");
        Log.i(TAG, "streamId: " + streamId);
    }
}
```

}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. HomeFragment had to @Override onCreate and inject itself with the following line

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ((DemoBaseActivity) getActivity()).inject(this);
}
```

Then it works for me.

I hope this will help other users on my level of understanding.